# How to serialize a class with a generic type using kotlinx.serialization

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have a data class that inherits from a sealed class that I want to serialize into a java.util.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

```
@Serializable
sealed class A

@Serializable
data class B : A {
    val x: String,
    val y: Int,
    val z: Boolean
}

@Serializable
data class C : A {
    val a: String,
    val b: Int,
    val c: Boolean
}

@Serializable
data class MyServiceCache(
    val someOtherProp = "Hello World",
    @Serializable(with = ConcurrentLinkedQueueSerializer::class)
    val networkCallQueue: ConcurrentLinkedQueue<A> = ConcurrentLinkedQueue(),
)
```

I also have a custom serializer

```
class ConcurrentLinkedQueueSerializer<T>(
    private val dataSerializer: KSerializer<List<T>>
) : KSerializer<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = dataSerializer.descriptor
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>) = dataSerializer.serialize(
        encoder,
        value.toList()
    )
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = ConcurrentLinkedQueue(dataSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
}
```

This is all good at compile time. When I attempt to serialize in my application at runtime, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Polymorphic value has not been read for class null
    at kotlinx.serialization.internal.AbstractPolymorphicSerializer.deserialize(AbstractPolymorphicSerializer.kt:67)
    at com.my.app.service.network.ConcurrentLinkedQueueSerializer.deserialize(MyServiceCache.kt:35)
    at com.my.app.service.network.ConcurrentLinkedQueueSerializer.deserialize(MyServiceCache.kt:27)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(AbstractDecoder.kt:43)
    at kotlinx.serialization.encoding.AbstractDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(AbstractDecoder.kt:70)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:168)
    at com.my.app.service.network.MyServiceCache$$serializer.deserialize(MyServiceCache.kt:16)
    at com.my.app.service.network.MyServiceCache$$serializer.deserialize(MyServiceCache.kt:16)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.StreamingJsonDecoder.decodeSerializableValue(StreamingJsonDecoder.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:107)
```

What's wrong with my custom serializer? I tried to follow the instructions in the documentation as best I could. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers-for-a-generic-type

Answer (score 0):

The [guidance you linked](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers-for-a-generic-type) says this:

> A generic class serializer is instantiated with serializers for its generic parameters.

What this means is that, when the framework instantiates a serializer for a generic class (say `MyClass<T>`) (with that serializer implementing `KSerializer<MyClass<T>>`) it passes an object of type `KSerializer<T>` to it. It does this so that serializer has the tool it needs to serialize whatever generic object(s) it contains.

You instead have put your [surrogate serializer](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#composite-serializer-via-surrogate) as the constructor parameter.

To follow the instructions, you need to rewrite with the serializer for the generic type `T` as constructor parameter. This will be provided by the framework at runtime:

```
class ConcurrentLinkedQueueSerializer<T>(
    serializerForGenericType: KSerializer<T>
) : KSerializer<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>> {
    private val surrogateListSerializer = ListSerializer(serializerForGenericType)

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = surrogateListSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>) {
        surrogateListSerializer.serialize(encoder, value.toList())
    }
        
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder) = ConcurrentLinkedQueue(surrogateListSerializer.deserialize(decoder))
}
```

The other thing done here is we have had to instantiate your surrogate serializer `surrogateListSerializer` by hand (using the built-in `ListSerializer`) using the provided generic serializer as parameter to do so (following the same above rule for serializers of generic classes).